# Backbone application with routes from a static json file (read-only)?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm building a read only backbone app with data (sourced from a single static json file) that follows a building/campus structure of sort. That is:

```
[{
    "name": "Building Name",
    "id": "building",
    "floors":[{
        "name":"Ground Floor",
        "rooms":[{
            "name": "Room 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Room 2"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name":"First Floor",
        "rooms":[{
            "name": "Room 3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Room 4"
        }]
    }]
    },
    {
    "name": "Another Building",
    "id": "building_2",
    "floors":[{
        "name":"Ground Floor",
        "rooms":[{

        }]
    },
    {
        "name":"First Floor",
        "rooms":[{

        }]
    }]
}]
```

I currently have a basic app set up that shows the list of buildings and floors for each building on a default '' route.

I would like to use the router so that APP/#buildingId/ shows the list of floors for a building with 'buildingId' and APP/#buildingId/#floorId shows the relevant list of rooms, etc.

**JSBIN of my current code (without data.json) - http://jsbin.com/welcome/5850/edit**

Lots of code is probably obsolete, but I was trying different ways to structure the models/collections. This app will never be more than read-only which is why I went with a static file.

---

Similar problem: [How to use JSON to power interactive Backbone.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670077/how-to-use-json-to-power-interactive-backbone-js-app)

The solution presented doesn't use the Router at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for?:

```
// code simplified and no tested
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "/APP/:buildingId/:floorId":  "showRooms",
    "/APP/:buildingId":           "showFloors"
  },

  showRooms: function( buildingId, floorId ) {
    // code to show the rooms
  },

  showFloors: function( buildingId ) {
    // code to show the floors
  },

});
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, pretty much this. I arrived at this stage now, where I play around with router functions, but I can't figure out the code to correctly show the floors or rooms. See updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uzohuy/1/edit This kind of works. On path APP/#0, which is the id of first building it returns the object correctly, but I can't access any attributes from the template apart from name. All attributes (apart from name) return error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined'. I can access all the attributes from console with: 'singleBuilding.models[0].get('name')'

Comment: @MiloszFalinski if I understand you are looking for a full implementation of a very personal case. I'm afraid this is out of the scope of StackOverflow. We can help you with more abstract and concrete issues non related with any concrete business logic.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure, but that's understandable. I got it mostly figured out by now, even though the code seems a bit hacky. Since your answer is pretty much what I went for, I'm happy to mark the question as answered.